# VueJs not hotreloading or picking up in DevTools

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I've been developing a new project over the past 2 weeks using VueJs + VueX and it's been working pretty well. I recently added a vue.config.js file to get my version number from my package json in the app.

Since I added this the hotreload stopped working and as of today the VueTools doesn't pick up that my website is a Vue site. When I want to refresh now I have to do a full refresh which slows down things a little bit because of some state refreshes.

This is only my second time using Vue for a real product, the first time I didn't see any of these problems. What could be the problem here?

I have no errors in the console, the app works fine, I just can't hot reload or do any dev things using the vue tools extension.

My vue.js.config file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("./package.json").version)
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    // host: 'localhost',
    // // disableHostCheck: true,
    // watchOptions: {
    //   poll: true
    // }
  }
};
```

**Things I've tried**

The things that are commented out are solutions offered different places on the internet, none of them worked on their own or all together

I've removed my node modules, re-installed, ran again using npm run serve and it didn't work.

I've restarted my machine and my Visual Code IDE multiple times.

I've hard refreshed my browser and cleared cache there

Where do I start to look if I want to find the problem for this and fix it myself?

**Update**

I'm one step closer. The hot reload works after I change my vue.config.js to

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.push[
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(require("./package.json").version)
        }
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

Vue tools are still not picking up in my browser, will update when I get that to work.

**Update 2**
Hot reload only sometimes works with the new config. I still have to reload for changes in my methods.

**Update 3**
That actually just broke my version fetching so I'm reverting back to my old config and just F5'ing for now.

Comment: Hey! As per the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration): `If you need conditional behavior based on the environment, or want to directly mutate the config, use a function (which will be lazy evaluated after the env variables are set).` change the way use `configureWebpack ` to `configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {`

Comment: @varit05 I've read through the docs. I don't see the relation to my debug environment not working and using this. Can you explain a bit more. I updated my config to match what you said but it makes no difference.

Comment: @varit05 using this setup seems to have worked when I don't set my plugins to one set of values but instead push a new one onto the plugins. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad I helped you. I am Adding it to answer. Please accept it.

Comment: @varit05 this only works for the hot reload, vue tools are still not working. I have the updated config in my question above, very different to what you recommended using production.env :/

Comment: @varit05 turns out it doesn't work all the time. Only some changes gets synced, I still have to refresh my browser for internal logic updates.